# Detecting git additions removed in later commit before merge

Tags: git, pull-request

Imagine the following commits, that are part of a Pull Request I am currently reviewing, that will be merged into master:

A--**B**--C--D--E--**F**--G

Now, imagine, **commit B** *introduces* brand new lines of code:

```
+
+ // Adding a useless comment
+
```

Now, imagine, **commit F** *removes* what commit B introduced:

```
-
- // Adding a useless comment
-
```

From a reviewer's point of view, these 2 *diff* should simply **not exist**.

The developer, since they are introducing new code then deleting it, should simply have amended commit B instead of removing their bogus code with commit F.

As a reviewer, I want to eliminate the "addition-deletion pair" entirely before I merge this branch into master.

Often times those addition-deletion pairs are part of much larger diffs and much much less obvious than my example, which makes them hard to spot.

**Is there a way for the reviewer to automatically detect those kind of bogus commits?**